# HTTP :: where browser send request to get file, does he waiting for response or he send request for next file?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest, http-headers

How HTTP request works:(if i have mistake, please write)

1. user type in browser http://www.website.com
2. the server send him html page with links to images+css+js files
3. browser read html and where included images/css/js file send http request to get the file

**where browser send request to get file, does he waiting for response or he send request for next file?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most browsers will have an internal queue of requests which are handled as follows:

Request the first item. If a fresh copy is in the cache, this will mean a request to the cache. If a stale copy with validation information (last-mod and/or e-tag) this will be a conditional request (the server or proxy may return a 304 indicating the stale copy is actually still fresh). Otherwise an unconditional request.

As rendering of the entity returned requires other entities, these will be put into a queue of needed requests.

Requests in the queue that have already been in that same queue (e.g. if a page uses the same image more than once) will have the same entity immediately used (hence if a URI returns a random image, but you use it more than once in the same page, you will get the same image used).

Requests will be processed immediately, so in the case of a webserver, images, css, etc. will begin downloading before the HTML has finished rendering or indeed, finished downloading.

Requests to the same domain with the same protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) will be pipelined, using a connection that has already been used, rather than opening a new one.

Requests are throttled in two ways: A maximum number of simultaneous requests to the same domain, and a total maximum number of simultaneous requests.

Answer (score 1):

The browser usually initiate more than one socket to the target server, and thus getting content on more than one socket at the same time. This can be combined with [HTTP Pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) (what you are asking about), where the browser sends multiple requests on the same socket without waiting for each of their responses.

From Wikipedia page:

> HTTP pipelining is a technique in
>   which multiple HTTP requests are
>   written out to a single socket without
>   waiting for the corresponding
>   responses. Pipelining is only
>   supported in HTTP/1.1, not in 1.0.